# How to NOT render newline break in Shiny renderUI?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am trying to wrap a line, which contains a newline break, inside a `<pre>` tag, however, once it's rendered, the newline tag is executed.  I don't want that to happen.  I thought including the `<pre>` tag would stop that from happening?

```
Current output:
this is
a test


Desired output:
this is\na test
```

Reproducible example:
Ignore the `<script>` tag, I'm only including it to show that there's more to this code than what's shown.  However, my main problem is not having the newline break execute.

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

  output$experience <- renderUI({
    div(
      pre(id = 'txt', 'this is\na test'),
      p(
        HTML("
              <div id='diagram'></div>
              <script>
              var diagram = Diagram.parse(document.getElementById('txt').innerText);
              diagram.drawSVG('diagram', {theme: 'simple'});
              </script>"
             )
        )
      )
    })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/js/webfont.js"),
            tags$script(src="https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/js/snap.svg-min.js"),
            tags$script(src="https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/js/underscore-min.js"),
            tags$script(src="https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/js/sequence-diagram-min.js")),

  htmlOutput('experience'))


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What's the desired output here? You don't want the new line to be put on a new line? The `pre` tag i meant to preserve new lines (it's one of the very few that does actually). If you want to strip newlines from a string, you can use something like `gsub()`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part. Desired output is to include the \n character, but to not execute it.  So:  'this is\na test' is what I want.

Comment: Then you need to replace the actual new line with a slash and the letter n. You can do that with `gsub(“this is\na test”, “\n”, “\\n”)`

Comment: Sorry, not following.  If I use this: pre(id = 'txt', gsub('this is\na test', '\n', '\\n')), then the UI outputs just '\n'.  When I want the UI to output the original text include the newline character, so 'this is\na test'

Comment: Sorry. I got my parameter order mixed up. It should be `gsub("\n", "\\n", "this is\na test", fixed=TRUE)` or `gsub("\n", "\\\\n", "this is\na test")`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, you have to include c() and it will output the desired output with newline character break, so:

```
pre(id = 'txt', c('this is\\na test'))
```

Outputs:
'this is\na test'

Comment: Actually, I think the solution is the double   ` \\\` and not the `c()`